Почему результат тестирования с помощью Unittest в Джанго отличается от результата мануального теста в моём проекте?
Пишу тесты для проверки функции комментирования постов в проекте на Джанго.
При тестировании в ручном режиме происходит следующее:

все пользователи могут просматривать пост, и видят форму для комментария.
неавторизованный пользователь при нажатии кнопки "Отправить" под формой комментария перенаправляется на страницу авторизации. После авторизации он попадает обратно на страницу поста, где может видеть свой только что опубликованный комментарий.

Так и должно быть. Но Unittest показывает, что после авторизации переадресация происходит на главную страницу.
class PostUrlTests(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()

        cls.author = User.objects.create_user(username='author')
        cls.creator = User.objects.create_user(username='creator')
        cls.group = Group.objects.create(
            title='Тестовая группа',
            slug='test_slug',
            description='Тестовое описание',
            creator=cls.creator,
        )
        cls.post = Post.objects.create(
            author=cls.author,
            text='Тестовый не очень длинный пост',
            group=cls.group
        )

    def setUp(self):
        self.authorized_client_creator = Client()
        self.authorized_client_creator.force_login(PostUrlTests.creator)
        self.authorized_client_author = Client()
        self.authorized_client_author.force_login(PostUrlTests.author)

    def test_redirect_to_post_detail_after_login(self):
        """Пользователь перенаправляется на страницу поста после авторизации"""
        self.user_with_password = User.objects.create_user(
            username='user_with_password', password='password')
        comment_text = 'Test comment after login'
        post_detail_url = reverse('posts:post_detail', args=[self.post.id])
        
        # Пытаемся оставить комментарий, будучи неавторизованным пользователем
        response = self.client.post(post_detail_url, {'text': comment_text})
        
        login_url = reverse('users:login')
        expected_redirect_url = f'{login_url}?next={post_detail_url}'
        self.assertRedirects(response, expected_redirect_url)
        
        # Имитация логина через форму
        login_response = self.client.post(
            login_url,
            {'username': 'user_with_password', 'password': 'password'}
        )
        
        # Проверяем, что после авторизации нас перенаправило на страницу поста
        self.assertRedirects(login_response, post_detail_url)
        
        # Проверяем, что комментарий успешно добавлен
        self.assertTrue(Comment.objects.filter(
            text=comment_text, post=self.post).exists())

Текст ошибки:
FAIL: test_redirect_to_post_detail_after_login (posts.tests.test_urls.PostUrlTests)
Пользователь перенаправляется на страницу поста после авторизации  
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dev\Yandex_Practicum\yatube_project\yatube\posts\tests\test_urls.py", line 97, in test_redirect_to_post_detail_after_login 
    self.assertRedirects(login_response, post_detail_url)
  File "C:\Dev\Yandex_Practicum\yatube_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 381, in assertRedirects
    self.assertURLEqual(
  File "C:\Dev\Yandex_Practicum\yatube_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 401, in assertURLEqual
    self.assertEqual(
AssertionError: '/' != '/posts/1/'
- /
+ /posts/1/
 : Response redirected to '/', expected '/posts/1/'Expected '/' to 
equal '/posts/1/'.

На всякий случай покажу код класса представления, но надеюсь, это не нужно, потому что он очень длинный:
class PostDetail(View):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        author = post.author
        author_posts = Post.objects.filter(author=author)
        post_count = author_posts.count()
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
        form = CommentForm()

        if (request.user.is_authenticated
                and 'comment_form_data' in request.session):
            form_data = request.session.pop('comment_form_data')
            form = CommentForm(form_data)
            if form.is_valid():
                comment = form.save(commit=False)
                comment.post = post
                comment.author = request.user
                comment.save()
                return redirect('posts:post_detail', pk=pk)

        context = {
            'post_count': post_count,
            'post': post,
            'author_posts': author_posts,
            'comments': comments,
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, 'posts/post_detail.html', context)

    def post(self, request, pk):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        form = self.get_comment_form(request)
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return self.handle_unauthenticated_user(request)

        form_data = request.session.pop('comment_form_data', request.POST)
        form = CommentForm(form_data)

        if 'comment_id' in form_data:
            return self.edit_comment(request, form_data, pk)

        if 'delete_comment_id' in request.POST:
            return self.delete_comment(request, pk)

        return self.add_or_render_comment(request, form, post, pk)

    def get_comment_form(self, request):
        return CommentForm(request.POST)

    def handle_unauthenticated_user(self, request):
        request.session['comment_form_data'] = request.POST
        return redirect(f'{reverse("login")}?next={request.path}')

    def edit_comment(self, request, form_data, pk):
        comment_id = form_data['comment_id']
        comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=comment_id)
        if comment.author != request.user:
            return redirect('posts:post_detail', pk=pk)
        form = CommentForm(form_data, instance=comment)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            if request.is_ajax():
                return JsonResponse({'text': comment.text})
        return redirect('posts:post_detail', pk=pk)

    def delete_comment(self, request, pk):
        comment_id = request.POST['delete_comment_id']
        comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=comment_id)
        if comment.author == request.user:
            comment.delete()
        return redirect('posts:post_detail', pk=pk)

    def add_or_render_comment(self, request, form, post, pk):
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            if request.is_ajax():
                return JsonResponse({
                    'id': comment.id,
                    'username': comment.author.username,
                    'text': comment.text,
                    'profile_url': reverse(
                        'posts:profile', args=[comment.author.username])
                })
            return redirect('posts:post_detail', pk=pk)
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
        author_posts = Post.objects.filter(author=post.author)
        post_count = author_posts.count()
        context = {
            'post_count': post_count,
            'post': post,
            'author_posts': author_posts,
            'comments': comments,
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, 'posts/post_detail.html', context)


В "имитации логина через форму" вы не отправили параметр next, и в итоге Django неоткуда знать куда переадресовывать

@andreymal Спасибо! Это помогло.
